# How to change the position of a line in PHP?

Tags: php, woocommerce

How to change the position of a line in PHP?
I'm trying to add a custom text line in the woocommerce product description tab.
But it's coming at the bottom of the tab. I want the line at the top of the page. How can I do that?

I'm using this code.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'customizing_woocommerce_description' );
function customizing_woocommerce_description( $content ) {
    // Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( is_product() ) {

        // The custom content
        $custom_content = '<p class="custom-content">' . __("This is the last line in the description", "woocommerce").'</p>';

        // Inserting the custom content at the end
        $content .= $custom_content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$content .= $custom_content` means `$content = $content . $custom_content;`

You probably need this if I understood correctly:

```
$content = $custom_content . $content;
```

**So, complete code:**

```
// Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
if ( is_product() ) {

    // The custom content
    $custom_content = '<p class="custom-content">' . __("This is the last line in the description", "woocommerce").'</p>';

    // Inserting the custom content at the end
    $content = $custom_content . $content;
}
return $content;
```